# Unable to install npm package due to encoded url

Tags: windows, npm, gitlab, urlencode

So I recently got a Windows laptop at work, trying to set up my dev environment and I am getting a strange issue when trying to install our private gitlab npm packages.

I try npm install and it says it cannot find the package even though it has been published to our private registry. This seems to only be happening on my windows machine. The package can be found no problem on my macbook.

```
npm i
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://gitlab.orgname.com/api/v4/projects/118/packages/npm/@integrations%2fcommon-ui
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@integrations/common-ui@^1.0.4' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jack.lovett\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-13T10_08_06_142Z-debug-0.log
```

It seems that / in the path is being encoded to %2f so then it can't find the package anymore.

I can't find any help online for this issue so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Searching for "npm 2f" pulls up a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The `%2f` part in the url seemed to not be relevant and just caused me to go down a rabbit hole of unrelated issues.

What seemed to be the problem was that i did not have NVM correctly set to my PATH in my environment variables.

When adding to path I added the location of my `/node.js` directory in `/"Program Files"/node.js`. This then added to my path the correct node version used by nvm.

I then attempted to authenticate with our private package registry again and it all worked as expected.